# Background-size-polyfill does not work in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, background-size

I have this simple code:

```
<html style = "height: 100%;">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv = 'Content-Type' content = 'text/html; charset = windows-1251' />
        <title>test bg</title>
    </head>

    <body style = "height: 100%; margin: 0px;">
        <div id = 'div_0' style = "width: 100%; height: 100%; background-size: contain; -ms-behavior: url(backgroundsize.htc); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-image: url(storage/zast_800x600.jpg);"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

No any errors when page is loaded. But background acts same as without this thing.

**`.htaccess`** and **`backgroundsize.htc`** is in same folder with html page. I run this file locally by double clicking html page.

[image]

I am using ***[PolyFill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill)*** as reference

Comment: Yes try above edits and see if it works

Comment: @Richa - nothing from that works. And still no any errors.

Comment: Can you give a demo page or working demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>`.htaccess` won't do anything in your Windows filesystem, such as serving the file with the correct MIME type to IE, which is required for `.htc` files to do anything. You need to place it inside a running Apache server; it's a list of instructions for the server to perform.</s>

If you don't have access to a development server or something else already established, you could try [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or another method of getting a local Apache server running.

Turns out the real answer was found on GitHub elsewhere. The asker wasn't running in Standards mode, causing the `ms-behavior:` declaration to fail; Quirks mode only recognizes `behavior:`.

Comment: Then, I don't know how, but the index.html page that comes in package works in that way. I start it from folder by double clicking and images resizes correctly in IE8.